# Writing HTML with Python xlwt module

Tags: python, xlwt

I'm using xlwt to write an Excel formatted file, and I want to include html in a cell. What parameters do I need to provide to hint that Excel should render the content?

Comment: Let me clarify, you want to put raw html as the content of a cell and have excel render it?

Comment: @Steven: yes that's what I'd like to do if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can do it manually using the Excel 2003 user interface, then there's some chance of doing it with current `xlwt`, or making `xlwt` do it. Please edit your question to show what keyboard/mouse actions are required.

If you can't do it manually, then `xlwt` definitely can't do it either. Have you explored all the cell formatting possibilities? What is the underlying user requirement? Would it be satisfied by a link to a web page?

See relevant SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842071/can-excel-interpret-a-cell-as-html).

By the way: (1) I'm the maintainer of `xlwt`. (2) Consider asking questions on the python-excel forum (see http://www.python-excel.org) ... they are likely to be answered faster than here.

Comment: The relevant question you linked to makes it sound like Excel won't format the html properly. I would like to try on my own, but I don't have access to Excel 2003. Do you know if there is a '2003 compatibility mode' type feature in 2010?

Comment: @limscoder: The general technique would be to get whatever it is that you are experimenting with working in Excel 2010 if you can, "save as" Excel 97-2003, exit Excel, start Excel again, open the 97-2003 xls file, check if it's still doing whatever it was.