# excel - formatting html data and writing back to same cell - performance issue

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I have a excel with **column "A"** containing non-formatted html data. To format this data, I am following the below steps:

1) Take the non-formatted html data from first cell and paste it on Internet explorer and paste the formatted text from html page to excel **column "E"**  ([HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell))

2) From the excel column "E", read the data from each row to final row and paste to the original cell **preserving the formatting** and i use the below code for that.

```
Sub ConcatenateRichText(Target As Range, Source As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Long
    i = 1
    With Target
        .Clear
        For Each Cell In Source
            .Value = .Value & vbLf & Cell.Value
        Next Cell
        .Value = Trim(.Value)
    End With
    For Each Cell In Source
        For c = 1 To Len(Cell.Value)
            With Target.Characters(i, 1).Font
                .Name = Cell.Characters(c, 1).Font.Name
                .FontStyle = Cell.Characters(c, 1).Font.FontStyle
                .Size = Cell.Characters(c, 1).Font.Size
                .Strikethrough = Cell.Characters(c, 1).Font.Strikethrough
                .Superscript = Cell.Characters(c, 1).Font.Superscript
                .Subscript = Cell.Characters(c, 1).Font.Subscript
                .OutlineFont = Cell.Characters(c, 1).Font.OutlineFont
                .Shadow = Cell.Characters(c, 1).Font.Shadow
                .Underline = Cell.Characters(c, 1).Font.Underline
                .ColorIndex = Cell.Characters(c, 1).Font.ColorIndex
            End With
            i = i + 1
        Next c
        i = i + 1
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

The problem is this code takes too much time to format the data, For 54 rows it is taking almost 10 minutes...

Is there any better solution for this?

Here is the link for complete code http://pastebin.com/fZbQPYbg

Thanks in Advance

**Note:** Posted the same question on [mrexcel.com](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/702284-excel-formatting-html-data-writing-back-same-cell-performance-issue.html#post3468839).I will update here if i get any anwers

Comment: you need to show complete code to judge. I think you possibly open each time Internet App which is time consuming and unnecessary. Do you have `Application.ScreenUpdating` set to `false` in your subroutine... etc. So, show complete code.

Comment: Thanks KazJaw, Here is the complete code : http://pastebin.com/fZbQPYbg

Comment: first, you use to much `select` method in your subroutine which is not recommended. There are some Q&A here in SO where you find ways to avoid it (Indeed, `selectiong` is time consuming). Second- add at the very beginning of your `Main` sub this line: 'Application.ScreenUpdating = false` and set it  back to `true` just before finishing `MsgBox`. I think both tips will help...

Comment: @javanoob, can you confirm if the suggestions of @KazJaw helped?  If you concatenate line 7 and 8 of your pastebin code to `Columns("A:AB").NumberFormat = "General"` for example, and you do that wherever you have `.Select`, you'll definitely notice an improvement.  If so, can you mark the question as answered?