# Rendering simple html code in Powerpoint text box

Tags: html, vba, rendering, powerpoint

I have this string of html code and I want to display it in a Powerpoint Text box properly formatted as per the HTML code using VBA.

Any suggestion on how I do that?

I inserted some spaces in the code below to make it visible

Code:

```
< div> < font face=Arial color=black>&nbsp;</font><font face=Arial size=2 color=black><strong>Heading < /strong>< /font>< /div>

< div> & nbsp;< /div>

< div>< font face=Arial size=2 color=black>Text Sample< /font>< /div>
```

Comment: try to use [any of these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell)

Comment: What problem are you having? Also you will need `&&` to make the `&` show up.