# How to superscript one half of a cell and subscript the other half in excel

Tags: excel

This applies specifically when you are using a formula in a cell. What I want to do is have the left half of the cell superscripted, the right half subscripted, and I'm going to put a slash through the middle.  This can be accomplished with just words in the cells if you highlight the left word, superscript in, then subscript the right word, and add the slash border, like so:

[image]

This doesn't appear to be the case when you are using a formula instead of words.  I don't think its possible through the text or similar functions(I'd love to be proven wrong), so I've resorted to VBA, which looks to be a dead end so far as well since it either sets the property to superscript or subscript, but not both(it ignores the subscript in the following code).  I guess the root of the question is how can the cell have separate superscript/subscript properties set through the format cell GUI, but not through VBA.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub formatTable()
Dim tempVar As Range
Set tempVar = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")
tempVar.Characters(0, 4).Font.Superscript = True     'Left Side
tempVar.Characters(10, cint(len(tempVar)-4)).Font.Subscript = True     'Right Side
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this cell a formula or text? If formula, the output is "left / right"?

Comment: The cell is a formula.  And the output would be =foo & "    " & bar.  If you look at the vba code you can see I'm trying to superscript the first 4 characters and subscript everything after the 10th(arbitrary points I picked)

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that with a formula.  It would have to be static text

Comment: This http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/02/23/html-in-cells-ii/ may be useful to you - allowing you to have the cell contents as a snippet of HTML. Your cell would contain something like `="<html><sup>left</sup><sub>right</sub></html>"`

Comment: @dav1dsm1th wow, that's clever.  I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th bingo, it worked.  I didn't go the route that link did, rather I passed it through an IE object and pasted the results back instead, but same idea.  Thanks a ton, this trick opens up so many possibilities.

Comment: I saw the IE option and thought it may create too much of a dependency on the browser being available (hence the solution I suggested) - but glad I steered you in a useful direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone finds this question and is still looking for a solution (from my comment to OP):-

> This [article](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/02/23/html-in-cells-ii/) may be useful to you - allowing you to have the cell
>   contents as a snippet of HTML. Your cell would contain something like
>   `="<html><sup>left</sup><sub>right</sub></html>"`

It's also possible to offload the rendering to IE as detailed in this StackOverflow [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell) which is the route OP took.