# Displaying formatted HTML text in Microsoft Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

I need to display text with html tags within a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet.

I need

`<strong>This should appear in bold - but you should not see the strong tags</strong>`

to appear in a cell of the spreadsheet as bold-faced text - without strong tags at the beginning and end.

**This should appear in bold - but you should not see the strong tags**

Answer (score 0):

i do not think excel supports this. the only way is to write some vba code that does it for you... maybe there is an addin available that does that job

try this:

[HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell)