# How to convert HTML to Text to cells Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I had the same problem with this one below:

[HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I entered the code as the given answer:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ie As Object

    Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With Ie
        .Visible = False

        .Navigate "about:blank"

        .document.body.InnerHTML = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

        .document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy"
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

but I got this message:

> "Run-time error '438':
>
> Object doesn't support this property method"

I am new at using VBA on excel and I don't know what to do

I appreciate any help

Comment: what version of excel?

Comment: Which line returns the error? Btw, have you tried DK's solution in the link you posted?

Comment: did you try my solution? if it worked please accept by clicking the tick beside the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub EXCEL_TO_HTML_RANGE()
Dim path As String
Dim rng As Range

path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\Book1.htm"
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 3))

With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, path, "Sheet1", _
    rng.Address, xlHtmlStatic, "Name_Of_DIV", "Title_of_Page")
    .Publish (True)
    .AutoRepublish = False
End With
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub EXCEL_TO_HTML_WORKBOOK()
Dim path As String
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\Book1.htm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path, FileFormat:=xlHtml
End Sub
```

[Reference](http://www.databison.com/html-to-excel-using-javascript-and-excel-to-html-using-vba/)

or you could use this macro

```
Public Sub RangeToHTM(MyRange, DocDestination, sCaller)
    ' This macro converts an Excel range to a HTML Table.
    '
    ' Copywrite 1996 - 2011 by Charles Balch, mailto:charlie@balch.edu
    ' Original Source is at http://balch.org/charlie/hdoc/exceltohtml.html
    ' MyRange is an Excel range you wish to convert.
    ' DocDestination is the FileName and Path to send the document to.
    '
    Dim lRGB As Long
    Dim strTitle, MV, CellV, CellA, BGC, Red, Green, Blue, SFC1, strComment, sTable As String
    Dim RowStart, Row, RowCount, RowEnd, ColStart, Col, ColCount, ColEnd, Hza, ColSpan, iFreeFile As Integer
    Dim SameTitle, blnIFrame, blnBoilerPlate As Boolean
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim fPage As TextStream

    If InStr(DocDestination, "iFrame_") Then blnIFrame = True 'The result will be optimized to use as an iFrame
    If InStr(DocDestination, "bp_") Then blnBoilerPlate = True 'The result will be optimized to for inserting into other HTML documents
    RowStart = Range(MyRange).Row
    ColStart = Range(MyRange).Column
    ColCount = Range(MyRange).Columns.Count
    RowCount = Range(MyRange).Rows.Count
    RowEnd = RowStart + RowCount - 1
    ColEnd = ColStart + ColCount - 1
    If Len(Dir(DocDestination)) > 1 Then Kill DocDestination
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set fPage = fso.CreateTextFile(DocDestination, True, True)
    If blnBoilerPlate Then 'Skip header if boilerplate
        sTable = "<table bgcolor=""#FFFFFF"" border=""1"" align=""center"" >"
        fPage.WriteLine "<!-- Begin Boilerplate " & strTitle & " -->"
    Else
        fPage.WriteLine "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"">"
        fPage.WriteLine "<html>" & vbCr
        fPage.WriteLine "<head>" & vbCr
        'fPage.WriteLine "<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html;charset=UTF-8"">" & vbCr
        fPage.WriteLine "<style type=""text/css"">" & vbCr
            fPage.WriteLine "body, td, tr, p, h1, h2, h3  { font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #00008B; font-size: 100% }" & vbCr
            fPage.WriteLine "a { color: #0000FF }" & vbCr
            fPage.WriteLine "a:hover { color: #8F0000}" & vbCr
        fPage.WriteLine "</style>" & vbCr
        strTitle = removeHTML(Cells(RowStart, ColStart))
        fPage.WriteLine "<title>" & strTitle & "</title>" & vbCr ' Use first cell as title
        'Note you may want to use your own style sheets or just remove the sheets entirely
        If blnIFrame Then
            fPage.WriteLine "<link rel=""StyleSheet"" href=""http://balch.org/iframe.css"" TYPE=""text/css"">" & vbCr
        Else
            fPage.WriteLine "<link rel=""StyleSheet"" href=""http://balch.org/excel.css"" TYPE=""text/css"">" & vbCr
        End If
        fPage.WriteLine "</head>" & vbCr
        sTable = "<table bgcolor=""#FFFFFF"" border=""1"" align=""center"" >"
        If blnIFrame Then
            fPage.WriteLine "<body >" & vbCr
            sTable = "<table bgcolor=""#FFFFFF"" border=""1"" align=center width=""100%"" >" & vbCr
        Else
            fPage.WriteLine "<body bgcolor=""#9F9F9F"" >" & vbCr
        End If
    End If
    fPage.WriteLine sTable & vbCr
    While Row < RowCount
        Row = Row + 1
        DoEvents
        If (Not Range(MyRange).Rows(Row).Hidden) Then
            MV = ""
            Col = 0
            While Col < ColCount
                Col = Col + 1
                CellV = ""
                CellA = ""
                If (Not Range(MyRange).Columns(Col).Hidden) Then
                    'Define cell color
                    lRGB = Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).Interior.Color
                    Red = Hex(lRGB And 255)
                    If Len(Red) = 1 Then Red = "0" & Red
                    Green = Hex(lRGB \ 256 And 255)
                    If Len(Green) = 1 Then Green = "0" & Green
                    Blue = Hex(lRGB \ 256 ^ 2 And 255)
                    If Len(Blue) = 1 Then Blue = "0" & Blue
                    BGC = " bgcolor=""#" & Red & Green & Blue & """ "
                    If BGC = " bgcolor=""#FFFFFF"" " Then BGC = ""
                    CellV = Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).Text
                    If CellV = "" Then
                        CellV = "<br />"
                    Else
                        'Adjust Text
                        If Left(CellV, 1) <> "<" Then CellV = Replace(CellV, Chr(10), (Chr(10) & "<br />")) 'Add Line Feeds unless HTML
                        'Proposed by Dan Hinz Not used as it looks like it converts the entire cell to the first hyperlink.
 '                       If Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).Hyperlinks.Count = 1 Then
 '                          CellVH = "<a href=""" & Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).Hyperlinks(1).Address & """ target=""NewPage"">"
 '                          CellV = CellVH & Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).Text & "</a>"
 '                       End If

                        'Add Link to my home page
                        Select Case sCaller
                            Case "AWC"
                                CellV = Replace(CellV, "Charles V. Balch PhD", "<a href=""http://virgil.azwestern.edu/~cvb"">Charles V. Balch PhD</a>", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
                            Case "CVB"
                                CellV = Replace(CellV, "Charles V. Balch", "<a href=""http://charlie.balch.org"">Charles V. Balch</a>", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
                            Case "NAU"
                                CellV = Replace(CellV, "Charles V. Balch PhD", "<a href=""http://oak.ucc.nau.edu/cvb23/"">Charles V. Balch PhD</a>", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
                        End Select

                        'Define cell alignment
                        Hza = Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).HorizontalAlignment
                        CellA = " align=""left"" "
                        If IsNumeric(CellV) Then CellA = " align=""right"" "
                        If Hza = -4108 Then CellA = " align=""center"" "
                        If Hza = -4131 Then CellA = " align=""left"" "
                        If Hza = -4152 Then CellA = " align=""right"" "
                        If Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).Font.Bold Then CellV = "<b>" & CellV & "</b>"
                        If Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).Font.Italic Then CellV = "<i>" & CellV & "</i>"

                        CellVA = ""
                        vCA = Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).VerticalAlignment
                        If vCA = -4160 Then CellVA = " style=""vertical-align: top"" "
                        If vCA = -4107 Then CellVA = " style=""vertical-align: bottom"" "
                        If vCA = -4108 Then CellVA = " style=""vertical-align: middle"" "
                        'Define cell font color
                        lRGB = Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).Font.Color
                        SFC1 = ""
                        Red = Hex(lRGB And 255)
                        If Len(Red) = 1 Then Red = "0" & Red
                        Green = Hex(lRGB \ 256 And 255)
                        If Len(Green) = 1 Then Green = "0" & Green
                        Blue = Hex(lRGB \ 256 ^ 2 And 255)
                        If Len(Blue) = 1 Then Blue = "0" & Blue
                        SFC1 = "<font color=""#" & Red & Green & Blue & """ > "
                        If SFC1 = "<font color=""#000000"" > " Then
                            SFC1 = ""
                            SFC2 = ""
                        Else
                            SFC2 = "</font>"
                        End If
                    End If

                    'Check for Merged Cells (rows only)
                    If Hza = 7 Or Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).MergeCells Then
                        ColSpan = 0
                        SameTitle = True
                        While (Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).HorizontalAlignment = 7 Or Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).MergeCells) And SameTitle
                            ' The following code must be changed for versions of Excel earlier than 97
                            If Not Range(MyRange).Columns(Col).Hidden Then ColSpan = ColSpan + 1
                            Col = Col + 1
                            If Len(Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).Text) > 1 Or Not Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col).MergeCells Then
                                SameTitle = False
                                Col = Col - 1
                            End If
                        Wend
                        If ColSpan > ColCount Then ColSpan = ColCount
                        CellA = CellA & " colspan=""" & ColSpan & """ "
                    End If
                    'Check for Comment (Idea from Michal Matula)
                    sComment = funTestForComment(Range(MyRange).Cells(Row, Col))
                    If sComment <> "" Then 'The cell does not have a comment
                        sComment = Replace(sComment, Chr(34), Chr(147))
                        sComment = " title=""" & sComment & """"
                        CellV = "<a name=""Comment"" " & sComment & " >" & CellV & "</a>"
                    End If
                    MV = MV & "<td " & CellA & BGC & CellVA & ">" & SFC1 & CellV & SFC2 & "</td>"
                End If
            Wend
            fPage.WriteLine "<tr>" & vbCr & MV & vbCr & "</tr>" & vbCr
        End If
    Wend
    fPage.WriteLine "</table>" & vbCr
    If Not blnBoilerPlate Then
        fPage.WriteLine "</body>" & vbCr
        fPage.WriteLine "</html>" & vbCr
    Else
        fPage.WriteLine "<!-- End Boilerplate -->"
    End If
    fPage.Close
    Set fPage = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

[Reference](http://charlie.balch.org/hdoc/excel2010.txt)