# Insert HTML into Excel cell

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, excel, export-to-excel

I have an auditing system built in ASP.NET and C#, where users can insert comments, and those comments can be HTML formatted with tables `(<table>)`, "enters" `(<br>)`, lists `(<ul><li>)`, underlined text `(<u>)`, latin-accented leters (í, ó, á, é, ú), among others.

I need to export those comments into Excel cells, and that its HTML elements to render correctly, only in ONE cell.

It should look like this:
[image]

I tried with **interop**, but I just see it as plain text

```
 worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = htmlText;
```

Like this:
[image]

I also tried copying it to the **clipboard**, but I get a mess:

```
Clipboard.SetText(htmlTable);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlexcel.Visible = true;

xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = (Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];

CR.Select();

xlWorkSheet.Paste(CR, false);
```

And I see it like this

[image]

I also tried with [iceblue](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Document-Operation/Insert-HTML-Formatted-RichText-into-Excel-Cell-in-C.html) but it only supports "span" elements and paragraphs, not complex elements as tables, lists, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you've probably been downvoted because of the size of your question, it's quite broad and not as specific as SO typically likes. You need to break your problem right down into smaller tasks (for your sake too), have a go, and then post more specific problems you're having. Also, you need to show the code you have so far. If you don't have any, you'll probably get down-voted for not having a go first. I haven't downvoted you by the way, I don't necessarily agree with the general consensus towards use of downvotes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation JayMee! I tried to upgrade my question including what I have already tried.

Comment: Fair warning: Microsoft specifically recommends not running Excel automation on the server for various reasons:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found something similar here [html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell)

The difference is they are working in Excel and you've got an ASP.NET site; so we're going to have to get a bit creative.

Step 1: Reference the following COM object "Microsoft Internet Controls" (SHDocView)

Step 2: Add the following using statement to your code

```
using SHDocVw;
```

Step 3: Try the following code:

```
var ie = new InternetExplorer();
ie.Visible = false;
ie.Navigate("about:blank");
ie.Document.body.innerHTML = htmlTable;  //Yes, this is the correct casing
ie.Document.body.createtextrange.execCommand("Copy");

var xlExcel = new Application();
xlExcel.Visible = true;

var misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
var xlWorkBook = xlExcel.WorkBooks.Add(misValue);

var xlWorkSheet = (WorkSheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

var range = (Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
range.Select();

xlWorkSheet.Paste();
```

Comment: I was able to compile and run this on my side.  I'm using VS 2012 and the 4.5 framework.  How about you?