# Get formatted html from web to MS-Word

Tags: html, xml, vba, dom, ms-word

I have asked this question many time before with other questions. Never got answer.

**Is there any way to get webdata with formatting and put it in microsoft word?**

I got some solution based on this answer

[HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell)

In My case I am getting data directly from web. Is there any direct process to get formatted HTML content.

My code is:

```
If .Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
    HttpReq.Open "GET", .Hyperlinks(1).Address, False
    HttpReq.send
    oHtml.body.innerHTML = HttpReq.responseText
    StrTxt = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("class").Item.innerHTML
        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate "about:blank"
            .Document.body.innerHTML = StrTxt
            .Document.execCommand "SelectAll"
            .Document.execCommand "Copy"
        End With
    Set rng = Tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        rng.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
    Set rng = nothing
End If
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Word requires a converter to bring HTML into a Word document you basically have three choices:

1. Use the Clipboard (copy, paste)
2. Save the HTML as a file then use InsertFile
3. Parse the HTML with your code and "translate" it to valid Word object model commands.

"Better" is a matter of opinion and depends on what you mean by "better". Simplest is certainly what you're doing...

Comment: I don't have any idea about use the clipboard while working with HTML content. I will look into it. The problem with Simplest (above code) is it gives broken images if any. For that I need to run another macro (which is also not working fine and is under review as per your suggestion)

Comment: images are something else altogether and are not referred to in your question. Copy/paste uses the Clipboard, which is what you're doing. But the Clipboard can only work with what the web-page provides. Not everything in today's web pages is provided "in the clear". You might make some progress by attempting to copy/paste manually, noting which attempts do not work satisfactorily. Analyze the web page's "Source" to find out how the information is being provided, then ask in a group that specializes in that sort of thing whether it's even possible to pick up such images through copy/paste...