# Display an MS-Access record's Rich Text Format in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, dao, rtf, vba

**What I want to do**

I have an Access database ( C:\Users\289894\Desktop\Database1.accdb )
One of the fields of [Table1] is [Memo].

That field is of the `Memo` data type, with the text format set to `rich text`.
It makes it possible to save some records as **Bold** and some records saved as *Italics*, for example.

I want to open a connexion to this Access database from an excel file in order to read/write into this rich text field.

The code I used is the following:

```
    Dim datab As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim path As String

    path = "C:\Users\289894\Desktop\Database1.accdb"

    Set datab = OpenDatabase(path)
    Set rs = datab.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Table1]")

        Debug.Print rs!Memo
        Range("A1") = rs!Memo
```

**My question**

This code works well to open a connexion and read ordinary text fields, but rich text acts in a surprising way (for me). The original text in access was "**aaa**". That's "aaa" in bold font.

After running the code, both the debug.print and Range("A1") have `<div><strong>aaa</strong></div>` written into them.

How can I change my code to send the format to excel as well? I'd like to have "**aaa**" written in bold in cell A1, just like it is in Access.

**EDIT: Workaround**
This solves the immediate problem asked by the question without really answering the question itself. It uses internet explorer to paste the text back as Rich Text, without the tags.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ie As Object
    Dim rng As Range

        Set rng = Feuil1.Range("A1")

        Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        With Ie
            .Visible = False

            .Navigate "about:blank"

            .Document.body.InnerHTML = rng.Value

            .ExecWB 17, 0
            'Select all contents in browser
            .ExecWB 12, 2
            'Copy them
            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng


            .Quit
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. I don't have a straight up solution in terms of settings or user a different export method, but a hack you could use is to loop  the rowset after import and remove the `html` tags and make the cells bold, or italic, depending on the tag. Also the title seems to have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Good catch on the title, I'm not sure what had happened there. As for pasting back as HTML, I thought about it, but the best answer I found was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell and it throws an error for me (EDIT: It no longer works with newer IE versions).

Comment: Did you try this answer from the question you linked? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14951531/3820271

Comment: Yes, I also don't have the required library in my list and this code is supposed to run on several machines so importing librairies is not really an option.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that every Windows machine has FM20.dll, but it doesn't matter - there are other methods to put a string into the clipboard, e.g. http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0049.htm

Comment: "The original text in access was "**aaa**"" - actually, no. The original text stored in the Memo field is `<div><strong>aaa</strong></div>`. It is only interpreted and rendered as formatted text if the "rich text" flag is set for the table field or form control.

Comment: @Andre ok, then that means the question is more "How to display rich text correctly in Excel". Well the second portion of my question (the edit) answers that somewhat. Debating whether i should close this

Comment: I think your edit answers your question well. You have HTML stored in a record and you want excel to interpret that HTML as a browser would. Using the `pastespecial` method of the `worksheet` object and setting the `format` parameter to `HTML` makes Excel interpret the HTML and display it. Although, this answer is really using a combination of IE, Clipboard, and `Worksheet.PasteSpecial` to make that interpretation happen.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. Loop range is generic. Also, function assumes very limited HTML as shown in your example.

```
Sub Test()

Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Range("A1:A100")

    cel.Font.Bold = InStr(1, cel.Value, "<strong>")
    cel.Font.Italic = InStr(1, cel.Value, "<i>")
    cel.Value = RemoveHTML(cel.Value)

Next

End Sub

Function RemoveHTML(sHTML As String) As String

Dim sTemp As String
sTemp = sHTML

Dim bLeft As Byte, bRight As Byte
bRight = InStr(1, sTemp, "</")
bLeft = InStrRev(sTemp, ">", bRight)

RemoveHTML = Mid(sTemp, bLeft + 1, bRight - bLeft - 1)

End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately my example was just that, a limited example. The real end goal is to be able to send the field I want to a textbox (not a userform textbox) with its formatting. It can include font bolding, italics, size and color, among other things. My idea was to start by making it work in a cell (which I did successfully, will add my answer) and then figure how to change to code so I can send the rich text from the cell to a textbox. Since this particular question was unanswered in SO I figured fragmenting in two  would be better for later reference.