# Send Rich Text Formatting to Access from Excel cell via DAO Recordset

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

**What I have**

I have an excel cell, say "A1" with some formatted text. Say the text is underlined and bold and says "abc", with each letter being a different color.

In access, I have a Table with a Memo field, with the text format set to Rich Text.

**What I want**

Previously today, I managed to open a recordset from Excel, take an Access table field's text with the formatting, and send it to an Excel cell. Now what I want to do it the opposite, but still from Excel.

**What I tried**

I tried to send A1's formatted text to the Memo field when the ID = 4. Sending the cell's value doesn't keep the formatting, and sending the cell as an object either. Here is the code I tried:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim datab As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim path As String
    Dim str As String

    path = "C:\Users\289894\Desktop\Database1.accdb"

    Set datab = OpenDatabase(path)
    Set rs = datab.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Table1]")

    Do Until rs.EOF
        rs.Edit
        If rs!ID = 4 Then
            rs!Memo = Range("A1")
            rs.Update
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close

End Sub
```

Is there a way to send text so that Access stores it with its format WITHOUT manually having to check the whole string for formatting, adding HTML tags where necessary, and sending that instead? I hope not, and would like to know how to modify my code to send format with text!

Comment: I suggest you try using Binary data for the [DAO.Field](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html) representing the Memo field

Comment: How would that be translated into VBA when trying to send information to Access? I am sending the A1 range right now, but by default that sends Range("A1").Value, which I presume is purely text and not format. So I feel like the issue is not on the Access side, but on using the proper arguments to send.

Comment: Iv'e never dealt with Text Formatting, but getting over limitations *free tools* provide us is a hobby of mine... First: is the data in the XL cell saved in HTML? do you have a way to read this html, say display it in a msgbox?  that would be the easy way: somethig like `rs!Memo = Range("A1").htmlValue` (or `Cells("A1")`). I would dig in that direction.

Comment: Other suggestion: change the `Memo` field to a `binary` field, that way `rs!BinaryField = Range("A1")` will (maybe...) copy `bit`s, not text, and will (hopefully...) copy html tags as well. Then, when html is in Access table, it should be easier to convert Binary data to Memo data. Please Keep us (me) posted :)

Comment: @marlan I ended up using a macro to add HTML tags to the strings I send. It is very fast and not problematic. Access interprets the HTML if it is an RTF Memo field and it shows up as formatted in the tables. The real problem is the inverse problem; once Access sends back a HTML string, Excel doesn't put the formatting back. And I have a very hacky macro to reinterpret HTML back to formatted text...

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell) for you... ;)

Comment: That's what I'm using.. slightly modified ;) Unfortunately creating an IE object is the "best" way to do it, but it's pretty slow as you have to create the instance and then do it once cell at a time (as far as I could manage). I have a lot of cells to convert so it's a slow way. That's why I called it hacky. It'd be faster to have a piece of code to check the whole string for HTML tags and make it bold, underline, italics, set the color, etc. Depending on the tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116687/discussion-between-marlan-and-david-g).

Answer (score 0):

Access refers to the Memo format as "Rich Text", but if you look closely, the help says:

> Choose rich test to store text as HTML and allow rich text formatting.

That can be confirmed by inspecting the Value property of the field using DAO. The content of the field is definitely HTML.

So you don't need any RTF, but you do need HTML that is compatible with the Rich Text field. You may find that you need to copy the Excel value into Word or PowerPoint, and *then* into the Memo field. That sometimes generates more friendly HTML than Excel.

The safest way would be to build the HTML yourself, and although it's time consuming, you would have control over which formats are important, and how concise the HTML needed to be, and how much CSS was used. Excel's HTML tends to be verbose, so generating your own HTML could be useful to minimise the size of the memo field values.