# Navigate to blank page in IE with Excel

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have a piece of VBA code in Excel that takes cells where there is plain HTML text written, takes that HTML to IE, and pastes it back as formatted text without HTML tags in the cell. I picked the code here: [HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell)

Contrary to that question I linked, I have to do this for a LOT of cells, so I want to speed up a little bit. Since `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` takes a long time to process I am trying to use the same object several times, but it fails on the line `.Navigate "about:blank"` the second time it comes to it.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ConvertHTMLrecu()
    Dim Ie As Object
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iChr As Integer

    i = 1
    Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    For i = 1 To 40
        Set rng = Feuil3.Range("A" & i)
        Set rng2 = Feuil3.Range("C" & i)

        With Ie
            .Visible = False

            .Navigate "about:blank"

            .Document.body.InnerHTML = rng.Value

            .ExecWB 17, 0
            .ExecWB 12, 2

            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng2

            .Quit
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

**What I need**

I would like one of two things. Either find a way to navigate to a blank page again so I can run the macro a second time without having to reset the object OR find a better way to format HTML text in Excel (since this is all this macro is doing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quitting **`Ie`** object in first loop and trying to access same in second loop, hence getting error.

Just remove **`.quit`** from loop and place below lines in the last line just before **`End Sub`**:

```
Ie.quit
Set Ie = Nothing
```

Comment: Your answer was good but I'd still like to say that it doesn't work well at all in a loop. It throws intermittent errors and has mixed results that vary from execution to execution. The creator of the macro (linked) had warned that the method was prone to runtime errors...

Comment: Well, I've tried with some dummy data and it worked well. Also my answer is purely related to your question. If you can add some test data, I can take a look.

Comment: I managed to make it work properly, but it takes around 1/3 of a second per cell that needs to be converted. So your answer is great, it's just the execution speed that is bad.