# How to preserve the meaning of tags like <br>, <ul> , <li> , <p> etc when reading them in Java using JSOUP library?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am writing a program that extracts some certain information from local HTML files. That information is then shown on a Java JFrame and is exported to an excel file. (I am using JSoup 1.9.2 library for the HTML parsing purposes)

I am running into an issue where whenever I extract anything from an HTML file, JSoup is not taking HTML tags like break tags, line tags etc. into account and so, all the information is being extracted like a big chunk of data without any proper newlines or formatting.

To show you an example, if this is the data that I want to read :

> ### Title
>
> Line 1
>
> Line 2
>
>   Unordered
>     List
> - element 1
> - element 2

The data is coming back as :

> Title Line 1 Line 2 Unordered List element 1 element 2 (i.e. all the
>   HTML tags are ignored)

This is the piece of code that I am using for reading in :

```
private String getTitle(Document doc) { // doc is the local HTML file
    Elements title = doc.select(".title");
    for (Element id : title) {
     return id.text();
    }
    return "No Title Available ";
}
```

Can anyone suggest me a way that can be used to preserve the meaning behind the HTML tags by using which I can both display the data on the JFrame and export it to excel with a more readable format?

Thanks.

Comment: instead of `id.text()` use `id.html()`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I did try to use id.html(), it however returns the complete html code. What i am trying to get back is the text which has the same (or identical) formatting as the HTML appears on a webpage. Is there any way to get the data exported to excel with that HTML format? @Lashane

Comment: AFAIR, no, it is not possible

Comment: Don't remove the tags and try something like this in Excel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell

Comment: Do you have a HTML example?

Comment: Thanks @FredericKlein, adding code to Excel wasn't really something that i could do for my project as I am generating new excel files while processing the HTML, But it did taught me a lot of new stuff :)

Comment: Thanks for your input @DavidePastore, I was able to figure out a way and just posted it on this thread :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to give everyone an update, I was able to find a solution (more like a workaround) to the formatting issue. What i am doing now is extracting the complete HTML using `id.html()` which I am storing in a String object. Then, i am using the String function `replaceAll()` with a regular expression to get rid of all the HTML tags without pushing everything into a single line. The `replaceAll()` function looks something like `replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","")`. My whole *processHTML()* function looks something like :

```
private String processHTML(String initial) { //initial is the String with all the HTML tags
        String modified = initial;
        modified = modified.replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>",""); //regular expression used
        modified = modified.trim(); //To get rid of any unwanted space before and after the needed data
        //All the replaceAll() functions below are to get rid of any HTML entities that might be left in the data extarcted from the HTML
        modified = modified.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
        modified = modified.replaceAll("&lt;", "<");
        modified = modified.replaceAll("&gt;", ">");
        modified = modified.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");
        modified = modified.replaceAll("&quot;", "\"");
        modified = modified.replaceAll("&apos;", "\'");
        modified = modified.replaceAll("&cent;", "¢");
        modified = modified.replaceAll("&copy;", "©");
        modified = modified.replaceAll("&reg;", "®");
        return modified;
    }
```

Thanks you all again for helping me with this

Cheers.