# (Microsoft excel) Adding html tags to cells

Tags: html, excel, excel-formula, formatting

I'm trying to figure out how do i add for example <p>   and </p> at the beginning and the end of my cell data. So my data looks like this, example:

Before:  Los Angeles

After: <p>  Los Angeles </p>

I have a whole table with tons of content to be converted in this way. I would appreciate the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel is not a good HTML construction tool.

If you want to concatenate html tags with contents of Excel cells you can construct the final html string using the & operator between bits of text, like this:

```
="<p>"&A1&"</p>"
```

Edit: if you need to include formatted dates in this construct, you may want to look at the Text() function, like below. Adust to the format you need.

```
=TEXT(A1,"dd mmm yyyy")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works brilliantly. I only have issue with the date. It converts 8.6.2007 (day, month, year) into 39241 for some reason. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I added an option for dates. take it away

Answer (score 1):

Format the cell's value with TEXT using a custom format mask. The backslash can be used as an escape character to avoid conflict with reserved formatting characters.

```
=TEXT(A1, "\<\p\>@\<\/\p\>")
```

This format mask could also be used as a cell's custom number format.

[image]

```
<p>Los Angeles</p>
<p>Melbourne</p>
<p>Vancouver</p>
```