# Java : HTML to Excel cell

Tags: java, html, excel

Is it possible to add html text in an Excel's cell ?
For example if i have this html code :

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hello world
  </body>
</html>
```

And i want in the cell :
Hello World

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think Excel renders HTML like a browser would. Why do you need this as opposed to just putting in the desired text?

Comment: Do you have any code where you want to use this ?

Comment: @notyou I need to show html in a cell because i use the HTMLEditor from JavaFX to make Rich Text Format ( I need RTF)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell)