# VBA Script that will convert html to formatted text, and past multiple rows of data in the clipboard, into one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using this solution Ozmike's solution from here:
[HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell)

To convert a cell containing HTML into formatted text and pasting it in a new cell.

The conversion is working fine, however the issue is with the br tag, whenever it appears in the html, it causes multiple cells to be used when the formatted text is pasted

For example I have this:

```
<html><p>This is Line 1</p><p><br /></p><p><b>Note:</b> This is Line 2</p>
```

the result is:

[image]

the intended result is:

[image: [![[![enter image description here]

or with a space line between the two lines, that works too.

One Idea I had was to paste directly in the formula bar of the target cell. When I paste in that bar on my own it contains multiple lines into one cell, however loses the formatting, so I don't think this is an option. Is the intended result possible?

For reference the code used to achieve what I have so far:

```
Sub HtmlConvert()

Cells(1, 1).Value = "<html><p>This is Line 1</p><p><br /></p><p><b>Note:</b> This is Line 2</p>"
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
Worksheet_Change rng, ActiveSheet
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range, ByVal sht As Worksheet)

    Dim objData As DataObject ' Set a reference to MS Forms 2.0
    Dim sHTML As String
    Dim sSelAdd As String

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

            Set objData = New DataObject
            sHTML = Target.Text
            objData.SetText sHTML
            objData.PutInClipboard
            Target.Select
            sht.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: what if you were to first replace every `<br>` with `chr(10)`?

Comment: @oxwilder after tinkering some more using your suggestion, it seems the `<p>` also causes new lines in the final paste. The issue with this suggestion is that replacing these new line causing tags with `chr(10)` when the html is being converted to formatted text, it is no longer on seperate lines. I need the text to be formatted as the html intended (or at least look like it) but stay in one cell.

An alternative solution could be to replace all `<p>` and `<br>` tags with some kind of marker in plain text, and then format the seperate lines according to the markers after the conversion.

Comment: That being said, thankfully this would work for my purposes, as it is very hard-coded and I know how the '<br>' and '<p>' tags will always be formatted (that way I can hardcode their replacement) but if this was for a more dynamic purpose, for example if you didn't know exactly how the tags will be formatted and just want a catch all conversion this solution would leave something to be desired.

Comment: If this were used for a "more dynamic purpose", I would hope you would use an HTML library and actually parse the result instead of relying on Excel's copy and paste functionality.

Comment: @comintern, i'm a bit of a novice, are you saying convert the text myself by basically translating the tags to Unicode while entering text into a cell?