# HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell [python]

Tags: python, html, excel, format

Is it possible an HTML text with tag to put in an Excel Sheet as a fomatted text?

For example, I have a row HTML text:

```
<span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;color:darkgray'>DarkGray</span>
```

And I need to put it in Excel Cell as formatted text.

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQpKx.png)

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyPkb.png)

I found some VBA Scripts that actually work [VBA - HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell)

But since I am **scraping** with Beautifulsoup, and I am making a new Excel File all over again, it is not really helpful always to copy-paste the VBA Function manually.

I tried to transfer this Function in python code with win32client:

```
`Sub Sample()
Dim Ie As Object

Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 With Ie
 .Visible = False

 .Navigate "about:blank"

 .document.body.InnerHTML = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

 .document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy"
 ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

 .Quit
 End With
 End Sub
```

But I get an error "*** AttributeError: Excel.Application.document"

```
ExcelApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.visible = True

wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(old_file_path)

wb = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook

ExcelApp.Sheets("KW16").Select()

activesheet = ExcelApp.activesheet

col_end = activesheet.UsedRange.columns.count

row_end = activesheet.UsedRange.rows.count

ExcelApp.document.body.InnerHTML = activesheet.Range(activesheet.Cells(1,1), 
activesheet.Cells(row_end,col_end))
```

Is there any other way in python for ex. with openpyxl or xlsxwriter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [tablepyxl](https://github.com/martsberger/tablepyxl)

For example:

```
import tablepyxl

table = """<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-size:11.0;font-family:'Calibri';color:#a9a9a9";>DarkGray</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>"""

tablepyxl.document_to_xl(table, filename = r"test.xlsx")
```