# HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell with buttons for multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, html-parsing

I was working to preview the html code in excel and this reference works well

Re: [HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell/56501737#56501737?newreg=846458809b9447ed8b14e7d4bea3cfeb)

However, I am now trying to build a button for every single row (sort of like mail merge) so the aim is when I click on the button according to what row, the preview will show me the html code for that row.

For example, if I click on row 5 (A5) then I will see the html code for row 5 (A5).

The VBA code that I'm using is:

```vb
Sub HTMLPreview()
    Dim Ie As Object, RowNumber As Integer
    
    Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    With Ie
        .Visible = True
        
        .Navigate "about:blank"
        
        .document.body.InnerHTML = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
        
        '.document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy"
        'ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Can someone please help?

Screen shot for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJlBi.png)

Thank you heaps in advance

Comment: I don't understand what the inputs / outputs are. Is the input html in a cell and the output that html displayed as formatted text? E.g. <i>text</i> would give _text_  after pushing the button on that row, and then remain like that?

Comment: Correct.. A1:A22 has all HTML code and when you press the HTML button, the paragraph HTML code in A1 displayed in IE (browser) like reading a story. So the plan is, every single row has different story but when I click on the HTML button it shows the story according to the row. Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it will not open a new window for every button click, but tries to re-use a previously-opened IE.

Assign all your buttons to `ShowHTML`

```vb
Sub ShowHTML()
    Dim Ie As Object, html
    
    Set Ie = GetIE("about:blank") 'try to get already-open window
    If Ie Is Nothing Then
        Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'open a new IE
        Ie.Visible = True
        Ie.Navigate "about:blank"
    End If
    
    'Application.Caller is the name os the clicked-on button
    html = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Cells(1).Value
    
    Ie.document.body.InnerHTML = html
End Sub

'Find an open IE window which has a matching URL
Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object
    Dim o As Object, sURL As String, retVal As Object
    For Each o In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        sURL = ""
        sURL = o.LocationURL
        If sURL Like sLocation & "*" Then
            Set retVal = o
            'Exit For
        End If
    Next o
    Set GetIE = retVal
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.. keep getting "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" Any solution to this?

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: (Sorry I am very new to VBA and not sure what I'm doing), but it shows this when I press the Green Play button? https://ibb.co/D96c1Wg

Comment: In the VB editor go to Tools > Options > General tab >> Error trapping and set it to "Break in Class module".  Now you should get a "Debug" option when you hit an error. That code does not need to go in the worksheet code module though - you can put it in a regular module.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what you mean by regular module. What I did was, replace this my OP code with your code. Now I'm getting this error: https://ibb.co/D96c1Wg. Do you know what I did wrong? Appreciate your patient.

Comment: Right-click on the VBAProject in the treeview - Insert > module.  Move the code to that module and re-assign the macro to your buttons.

Comment: Thanks.. I managed to get to the module but comes back with the following issues https://ibb.co/VSs2nHj
https://ibb.co/Lt8gVJF  did I do anything wrong?

Comment: What is the error message when it stops?  Are you using Forms buttons?  That's what I tested with.

Comment: Sample:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OyqyZbohHE7NdMhqInWCXAM38AzMxIa8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you're legend.. It worked right away. Thanks heaps for your help. So much appreciated the time you spent to help. Thanks again.