# Workarounds to handle merged table cells in M2Doc

Tags: m2doc

In my document, I need to generate a table that has merged cells.
[simple example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh5TC.png)

As M2Doc does not support the merge of cells, I have tried two workarounds.

**Workaround 1**

It consists in creating nested tables inside the second column. I have played with the borders to hide the fact that it is a nested table.

[M2Doc template of workaround 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXioG.png)

Unfortunately Word does not handle nested table correctly, as there is no way to garantee the constant width of cells. Which results in columns that don't have a constant width.

[illustration of inconsistent column width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlI0B.png)

**Workaround 2**

My second workaround was to generate excel tables outside M2Doc, with Python4Capella. And in my M2Doc template, I create references towards the generated tables.

This second workaround would work well if I did not have to display XHTML descriptions in my table. So far, I can only get the markup code in Excel and I have no means to interpret it.

Any idea of how I could implement my table including merged cells with the current capabilities of M2Doc? For example with a dedicated Java service that I would develop? If so, any hint about how this service could be implemented is highly welcome. And so is any idea of strategy!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a Java service to merge cells for instance [this service](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/blob/fc10cdc22aca5e7ad01fa8111e3ccb73500d29d2/tests/org.obeonetwork.m2doc.tests/src/org/obeonetwork/m2doc/tests/services/MTableTestServices.java#L232).

Also you have [Excel services](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/m2doc_service_excelservices.html) to insert a table from an .xlsx file.

With Python for capella you will have to parse the XHTML from your description to use [OpenPyXL formating](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2021/08/11/styling-excel-cells-with-openpyxl-and-python/).

And maybe an other idea could be to use MS Excel itself to do the conversion via a [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell) or some cell format option.