# how to paste formatted html text in excel single cell

Tags: html, excel, format

My question is how do i paste the below html code in excel in a **single cell without losing format**

```
<html><body>
<b>first line</b>
<br>
<b>second line</b>
<br>
<br>
<b>third line</b>
</body></html>
```

How do i paste the above thing into excel **single** cell without losing format, like below but in single cell

[image]

**EDIT:** I am sorry there are related questions out there on how to paste the HTML data in excel but here the problem is how to paste the data in single cell

I found these questions related but my problem is slightly different
[Can Excel interpret a cell as HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842071/can-excel-interpret-a-cell-as-html)

Comment: I am really surprised that people are voting for off-topic for this question. The fact that if you cannot answer you vote for off-topic :)

Comment: If you feel so, You can always flag the question for moderation.. :)

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I had thought you just wanted to keep the new line formatting, not have the text formatted for you. I'm not sure whether you can do this. I've removed my answer. Good luck.

Comment: I am disappointed this was voted as off topic when so many excel questions are not.  I am trying to do exactly this and failing =D.  It would have been nice if people could have posted their work-arounds for preventing excel from auto-formatting pasted HTML.

Comment: For future people stumbling into this try pasting directly into the formula bar.

Comment: @Ted Thank you! Saved me a ton of frustration