# Export single line of HTML to Excel

Tags: html, vb.net, excel

I don't need to export a table, just a single footer line of html that is being stored in a database as a varchar. I am using an ExcelWorksheet:

```
Using package As New ExcelPackage()
    Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Proposal")
    ........
    ws.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = pr.Footer  'Where pr is database object
```

Again I don't need to export an HTML table, just a single line. The HTML is printing as plain text in the Excel document, I just want it to render.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Excel interpret a cell as HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842071/can-excel-interpret-a-cell-as-html)

Comment: Although this question might help you: [HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9999713/945456).