# Convert plain text HTML to real HTML MySQL > Excel

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, t-sql

I have exported my table contents into a .csv file that contains a column for `description`. This column contains some HTML in plain text format that I cannot use.

Example:

```
"&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Baby Rocking Horse Figurine&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;This cuddly bear is rocking back and forth into dreamland. 18 note movement.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;Tune: &lt;em&gt;&quot;Rock-A-Bye Baby&quot;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;5&quot; H&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;div id=&quot;image&quot;&gt;&lt;img id=&quot;zoomImage&quot; name=&quot;zoomImage&quot; src=&quot;http://www.sanfranciscomusicbox.com/core/media/media.nl?id=751799&amp;amp;c=969236&amp;amp;h=bc01a62cfec9b69d444c&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
"
```

Desired Output:

```
"<p><strong>Baby Rocking Horse Figurine</strong></p> <p>This cuddly bear is rocking back and forth into dreamland. 18 note movement.</p> <p>Tune: <em>"Rock-A-Bye Baby"</em></p> <p><em>5" H</em></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <div id="image"><img id="zoomImage" name="zoomImage" src="http://www.sanfranciscomusicbox.com/core/media/media.nl?id=751799&amp;c=969236&amp;h=bc01a62cfec9b69d444c" /></div> "
```

Is there a way to convert this into real HTML in bulk through excel or some other means? I have this data in MySQL as data type `Text`

Comment: Check this answer,you will get some idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842071/can-excel-interpret-a-cell-as-html

Comment: @alfrescolearner Thanks I was reviewing that answer also, as an alternative any way to export directly from MySQL in the proper format? The data is stored in my table as given in the example.

Comment: Also I don't need excel to actually render the HTML on the cell itself, rather just display proper HTML so I can re-import this somewhere else.

Comment: Try This one . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678980/is-there-a-mysql-function-to-decode-html-entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found SEOTools for Excel contains an HTMLDecode function you can use to acheive the desired result.

http://seotoolsforexcel.com/htmldecode/